# How can i using jquery for selectbox?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, refresh

i've got some problems on my selectbox. I want to selectbox's hold and set selected item after changing page or refresh.

Example: I'm selected country and city for "rent" category. And i changing category "sale". Page refreshing and same time holded selected option.

Sorry for bad language but i guess tell what i want.

Thanks.

This code on my site. How can i do this jquery and cookies.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>City</label>
    <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control" onchange="district()" >
      <option value="0">Choose City</option>
      <?
        $sql = $db ->query("SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY city_name ASC");
        while ($a = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="'.$a["id"].'"';  if ($_GET['city'] == $a["id"]){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } else { } echo '>'.$a["city_name"].'</option>';   
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you understand cookies or session? Go for that...

Comment: im not good jquery maybe someone share me working code. :)

Comment: You need to search internet. Or go to w3schools. It is better to learn jQuery as it is easy simple and cheese like.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie using the following function, when there is a change in the select value...

```
function setCountryCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
 if (!nDays) nDays=1;
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                 + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
```

Later onload of the page, read that cookie from you server script and keep that selected.

for example you can call the `setCountryCookie` function when the change of select value (jQuery Code something like this)-

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    setCountryCookie('country', valueSelected);
});
```

and read it from PHP while looping through.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['country'] && $_COOKIE['country'] == $a["id"]) { 
  echo ' selected="selected"';
}
```

Comment: Alright If I want to do this for more than one option? And If it does not bother you, can you prepare a working example in JSFiddle? :)

Comment: I'm trying to do this for my homework, but I have no idea about jQuery. I hope you understand.

Comment: Well I have given you a way to do it. You try with your code. If you understand JavaScript, you will understand jquery easily. Learn at w3schools.com